# How to delete connections from SQLTools on VSC?

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-code, sqltools

I made a connection in SQLTools once, but something gave an error so I deleted it. Now, when I made a connection, it doesn't show up or something like that and I don't know why. I thought maybe I could fix it by deleting my connections, but I don't know how. All my connections seem to be hidden and I can only see them (old connections, with new databases) when I press the button highlighted by the red circle in the picture. I was wondering if any of you know how to delete these connections, since I can't find it on Google.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

open vscode setting.json file (accessible from file>prefrences) and you should see an array called sqltools.connections just delete that and it resets.